# Oracle - no function with name X exists in this scope

Tags: oracle, oracle-cursor

The function is clearly there, because I can navigate to it using SQL Developer and it compiles all fine, but when I try to use the function with or without "call", it throws:

> Error(36,24): PLS-00222: no function with name 'x' exists in this
>   scope

This is how the function looks like:

```
create or replace function testfunction
  (
    somevalue in varchar2 
  )
  return varchar2
  AS
  cursor testcursor IS 
  select column1, column2 from table1 t
  where t.column1 = somevalue; 
  testcursorrec testcursor %rowtype;
  messaget VARCHAR2(500);
  begin
       open testcursor ; 
       fetch testcursor into testcursorrec ; 
       close testcursor ; 
       messaget := testcursor.column1;
      return messaget ;
  end;
```

This is how I'm calling it:

```
messaget := testfunction(somevalue);
```

where both messageT and somevalue are declared as varchar2 type.

Are cursors not allowed inside function or something like that?

Comment: Where is the "x" coming from?

Comment: Make your code simpler by losing the explicit cursor -- it's slower and more prone to errors in coding.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can access the cursor after you have closed it.

Comment: try calling messaget := schema_name.testfunction(somevalue)

Comment: @DavidAldridge, you mean I should declare 3-4 variables instead? (because this is only a dummy piece of code. In reality, I would need 4 columns from the row.

Comment: Regardless of the number of columns being selected you should not declare a cursor at all for this. Just declare the variables you will select into, "select ... into ... from ... where ... and rownum = 1" (whether you need the rownum = 1 is up to you) and then return the result.

Answer (score 1):

the error would be `messaget := testcursor.column1;` as the cursor is closed by then (you should just use `testcursorrec.column2`.

you're code isn't checking for no rows, nor duplicate rows. you can simplify this to

```
create or replace function testfunction
  (
    somevalue in table1.column1%type
  )
  return table1.column2%type
  AS
  messaget table1.column2%type; -- use %type where possible.
  begin
    select t.column2
      into messaget
      from table1 t
     where t.column1 = somevalue
       and rownum = 1;--only if you dont care if theres 2+ rows. 
    return messaget;
  exception 
    when no_data_found
    then 
      return null; -- if you want to ignore no rows.
  end;
```