# Returning a cursor , calling a procedure from other procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, sys-refcursor

I have 2 procedures in same package.
I wish to use  `QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE` in `QOT_LST_M_SEC_EXC_PRE`. In  `QOT_LST_M_SEC_EXC_PR`E I wish to find the argument - x_qot_id, call QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE with this argument and also return it instead of the statement. Can I do it? How.
I mean something  like

```
    PROCEDURE QOT_LST_M_SEC_EXC_PRE (
        i_sec_id     IN NUMBER,
        i_exc_id     IN NUMBER,
        o_recordset  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) IS x_qot_id NUMBER(10); 
        ------------------------------   
    BEGIN

    ---------------------------------------------------------------

    --call a function instead of writing query from this function
    open o_recordset for QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE(x_qot_id, o_recordset);
    ----------------------------------------------------------------

    END  QOT_LST_M_SEC_EXC_PRE;





     PROCEDURE QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE
    (
        i_qot_id     IN NUMBER,            
        o_recordset  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
        --------------------------------
    );
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: I'm getting this error: "PLS-00222: no function with name exists in this scope".

Comment: Have a look at this http://oracle-error.blogspot.com/2008/04/pls-00222-no-function-with-name-exists.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583574/oracle-no-function-with-name-x-exists-in-this-scope

Comment: I had a look before. It doesn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. You can declare out parameters of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` and use them in your procedures, here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE (i_qot_id IN NUMBER, THE_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) --Declare a sys_refcursor to be an out parameter, so it can be used outside
AS
BEGIN
 OPEN THE_CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM THE_TABLE WHERE X=i_qot_id;--Open the cursor
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE QOT_LST_M_SEC_EXC_PRE (i_sec_id IN NUMBER, i_exc_id IN NUMBER)
AS
x_qot_id NUMBER(10); --Test param
RESULT_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;--The cursor that will hold the opened cursor in QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE procedure
SOMEVARIABLE VARCHAR2(10);--Test variables to hold results of cursor
BEGIN
 QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE(1,RESULT_CURSOR);--Procedure will open RESULT_CURSOR
 LOOP --Loop cursor
    FETCH RESULT_CURSOR INTO SOMEVARIABLE;
    EXIT WHEN RESULT_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('READ :'||SOMEVARIABLE);
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE RESULT_CURSOR;--Close the opened cursor
END;
```

Comment: You can declare an `out` variable of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` in your `QOT_LST_M_SEC_EXC_PRE` declaration and open the cursor in the body of the procedure, as in `QOT_LST_M_QOT_PRE` code.

Comment: Yes, my question was how to do that.